# Run PHP CLI from Windows Powershell ISE

Tags: powershell, php

This question is regarding dollar signs "$" `$` in Windows PowerShell ISE.

I have PHP CLI and want to run one liner command scripts from the prompt in Windows PowerShell ISE.

`php -r "$foo = 'foo';"`

Just returns `Parse error: parse error in Command line code on line 1`  and I've narrowed it down to the pesky dollar sign which is significant in PowerShell.  Can I escape it somehow?

I also tried

`php -r '$foo = "foo";'`

and get

`Notice: Use of undefined constant foo - assumed 'foo' in Command line code on line 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, add a backtick in front of the dollar sign:

```
php -r "`$foo = 'foo';"
```

Comment: Also, I don't know if single-quotes are significant in PHP, but if OP encloses the command in single-quotes (and used double-quotes around `foo`), then there wouldn't be a need to escape the `$` as Powershell interprets anything in single-quotes literally.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need:

```
"`$foo = 'foo';"
```

Comment: Thank you, I found it right after I posted :)  I should have just searched a bit longer, but SO welcomes new content anyway.

Comment: I will. you know it doesn't allow that for a few minutes :p